# Вывод меток на карты с задержкой

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Имеется массив с геокоординатами.
Пытаюсь разобраться как сделать так чтобы метки выводились поочередно,  с задержкой (скажем секунда).
Адекватных решений пока не нашел.

То есть в данный момент добился того либо чтобы выводились либо все сразу(циклом но даже при наличие задержки в цикле выводит все ибо ymaps.ready(function () , 
либо по событию map.events.add('click', function ()  -  выводится как надо по одной по клику на карте, но во первых если надо вывести много - это же обкликаться можно + время от времени клик по карте приводит к изменению ее масштаба, что не есть хорошо.

Может есть какое-то свойство  или событие метки? Аля как у ломаной линии в примерах- AnimationTime: 4000

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: соберите, пожалуйста, свой пример, что вы уже сделали

Comment: Спасибо за желание помочь, но пока я приводил код в читаемый вид поступил ответ который полностью подошел. Поэтому не буду отвлекать Вас от помощи другим!

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вариант возможен:

```
var count = 0;
function addPlacemark(){
    myMap.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.684758 + count, 37.738521]));
    count++;
    if(count < 100) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        addPlacemark();
    },1000)
    }
}
addPlacemark();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xy1ak9Lq/

Comment: Спасибо- работает!